# Storing different types of AsyncTasks in one list

Tags: java, android, generics

## Case scenario

Suppose I need to store 3 `AsyncTasks` in the same list, and each one has a different set of generic types. For example:

```
public class FirstAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>()

public class SecondAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>()

public class ThirdAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,List<Integer>>()
```

How could I store the `AsyncTasks` in one list, while retaining the generic types?

I've tried saving them in a non-parametrized list like this:

```
List<AsyncTask<?,?,?>> asyncTasks = new ArrayList<>();
```

## The Problem

The problem I'm facing with this approach is that when I get one of the `AsyncTasks`from the list and try to call `.execute()`, a `ClassCastException` is thrown, here is the exception from the logs:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Void[]
```

(I'm using this line to get and execute the task)

```
asyncTasks.get(someIndex).execute();
```

Now I **do** understand why this is happening (because the most common type between those 3 Tasks is `Object`), but I can't come up with an idea to solve this problem. The probable answer to the question I'm about to ask is ***'Yes'***, but is there a way around this?

Comment: "I'm using this line to get and execute the task" -- but in two of the three cases, you're seeking to pass 1+ parameters to `execute()` (`String` for `SecondAsyncTask`, `Integer` for `ThirdAsyncTask`). You are only going to know what parameters to pass if you know which of these `AsyncTask` subclasses you are using, and if you know that, you know how to cast it. Also note that `AsyncTask` is not as popular as it used to be, and so you might wish to consider how newer approaches (`LiveData`, RxJava, etc.) might be applied in your situation.

Comment: You can add a method to your classes that will accept `Object[]` and in each particular class add implementation that will cast elements of that array to needed types

Comment: @CommonsWare how is LiveData helpful when I need to execute multiple asynchronous tasks? It is just a way to store observable data. Is there a different approach to do asynchronous operations like getting data from the web or IO operations other than `AsyncTask`?

Comment: "It is just a way to store observable data" -- sure. So is `AsyncTask`, in its own way: it stores the result and hands it to your `onPostExecute()` method. However, it requires very careful usage to avoid memory leaks on configuration changes (e.g., manage the `AsyncTask` in a retained fragment).

Comment: "Is there a different approach to do asynchronous operations like getting data from the web or IO operations other than AsyncTask?" -- use a repository that has a thread pool and exposes results via `LiveData`. Or, use RxJava (possibly fronted by `LiveData` for lifecycle management). Or consider Kotlin coroutines. Or look at pretty much any other reactive framework for Android that has come out in the past 3-4 years.

Comment: Don't you get any java compilation warning indicating that there is some unsafe cast ? If not it is likely that the warning is somehow supressed with [at]SuppressWarnings annotations. You can use the stacktrace to find out the probably location of the (suppressed) compilation warning.  Then you can changes this question to.... how I can get rid of the warning without supressing it, posting the problematic code lines.